# Parsing date in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a csv file in the following format

```
timestamp   curr_property   curr_property_cost  day_property    day_property_cost
12/16/2013 0:00 7211    123 48  281
12/16/2013 0:00 7179    123 72  281
12/16/2013 0:00 9627    165 104 282
12/16/2013 0:00 9610    165 136 282
12/16/2013 0:01 9691    166 168 283
12/16/2013 0:01 7034    120 191 283
12/16/2013 0:01 7018    120 215 283
12/16/2013 0:01 7050    121 238 284
12/16/2013 0:01 7018    120 262 284
12/16/2013 0:02 6970    119 308 285
12/16/2013 0:02 7034    120 332 285
12/16/2013 0:02 7083    121 355 286
12/16/2013 0:02 7018    120 379 286
12/16/2013 0:03 7034    120 402 287
12/16/2013 0:03 7002    120 425 287
```

The size of the data is huge so I want to reduce the size of the data I am accessing by taking every third value in the column.

How can I do this ? Also will this be the right way to parse the date

```
d3.time.format("%x %H:%M").parse;
```

Comment: This is not a CSV, it's a TSV and it won't work because one of your fields contains spaces.

Comment: I just wanted to show the order that the data is shown in, the file i have is a csv

Comment: Well, reducing the amount of data isn't really a Javascript question as you would need to do that when preparing the file.

Comment: will there be a difference is the way data is parsed from a tsv then from a csv 


This is my code. http://jsbin.com/henejuku/1/edit It is modified from the site link here http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955 which is using a tsv

Comment: You would use `d3.csv` instead of `d3.tsv`.

Comment: One last question, my date format is 12/16/2013 0:00 , so is d3.time.format("%x %H:%M").parse; the right way to parse it ?

Comment: Yes, it looks like it would be.